# Как научиться писать грамотно (только быстро и без усилий)?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Задан вопрос: **"Как взрослому, научиться быстро и без особых усилий писать грамотно"?** (Авторская пунктуация сохранена).

Вопрос весьма актуальный и обоснованный, соответствует известному суждению "20% усилий обеспечивает 80% результата". **Но вот ответы довольно банальные и безрадостные:**

1) Читать хорошие книги  в большом количестве. Желательно классику, причем изданную в Союзе, когда корректура и редактура была серьезная.

2) Начать с учебников и правил русского языка для учеников 1 класса. Только так и не иначе.

3) Прочитать учебник по русскому языку и освежить в голове правила.

4) Не получится быстро.

**Стало тут грустно автору вопроса**, всё это уже много раз слышал.  Но неужели нельзя ему помочь, может быть, есть  какие-нибудь **совсем новые методы и средства?**

Спасибо за ваши ответы.

Answer (score 2):

Абсолютно никаких средств. Так называемая "врождённая грамотность" формируется лет до 7-10. Если человек любит читать, естественно. И при этом еще обращает внимание на правописание. Чудес-то не бывает.

Вопрос, кстати, *совершенно* необоснованный. Вопрос халявный. Что делать, любят у нас халяву...

Comment: Представьте себе, что  вы высокопоставленный чиновник, а грамотность у вас не на высоте, неудобно перед подчиненными. Что делать? Учебники  для семилеток читать?

Comment: Вера, зачем для семилеток?  Достаточно проштудировать Розенталя на уровне ЕГЭ. Ведь есть хорошие справочники. Просто так взял да и выучил  - не бывает. Можно пройти курсы, наконец!

Comment: Серж, многие курсы рекламируют  свои абсолютно новые и самые эффективные методики, а вы спросите, в чем там новизна. Это тот же Розенталь на уровне ЕГЭ. Кроме того, слово штудировать мне не очень понятно, это опять заучивать, освежать в памяти и т.д.  Кстати, мне кажется,что память обладает каким-то иммунитетом против постоянно повторяющейся информации, в которой нет элемента новизны, человек  такие повторы перестает   воспринимать вообще.

Comment: Под словом "штудировать'' я  просто выучить наизусть ( язык вообще нельзя учить наизусть), а изучить весь материал,представленный в справочнике. Под курсами я не предполагал, что они предоставят новую методику, а лишь то, что они помогут изучить материал.

Comment: Чем плох Розенталь? Зачем искать чего-то неизвестного , если есть проверенный метод. Без усилий ничего не дается.

Comment: >> *Представьте себе, что вы высокопоставленный чиновник, а грамотность у вас не на высоте*  При всем желании не могу представить. Бедный чиновник... Боюсь, что ему придётся приложить неимоверные усилия, чтоб хоть чуть-чуть улучшить свою грамотность. Розенталя вызубрить можно, но это мало поможет, очень мало.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что тоже должна ответить на этот вопрос. Если его немного перефразировать: не как научиться грамотно писать быстро и без усилий, а просто - как научиться. Конечно, во-первых, должна быть какая ни на есть база, и согласна с тем, что закладывается она в детском и юношеском возрасте. Во-вторых, имея эту базу, очень до многого можно дойти самому, читая соответствующие книги, - справочники или даже просто пособия для заканчивающих школу (для подготовки к ЕГЭ, например). Но все же самое главное, без чего окончательно научиться, по-моему, невозможно - это живое общение, люди. Без общения невозможно понять многих нюансов, исключений, да и просто того, как то или иное правило работает. Настоящие знания может передать человеку только человек. Именно поэтому, скажем, дневное обучение лучше заочного. И поэтому я очень благодарна тем, кто, не жалея своего времени, отвечает на вопросы и помогает общими усилиями доискаться до истины. Спасибо!

Comment: Alenka, спасибо за ответ, и хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение по следующему вопросу: почему правила орфографии и пунктуации требуют дополнительных пояснений, почему разными людьми они толкуются различным образом. Это неизбежное свойство правил или они не очень ясно написаны?  Можно ли улучшить формулировку правил, не изменяя их содержания?

Comment: Я думаю, что скорее неизбежное. Разночтения возникают именно потому, что каждый понимает по-своему, на своем уровне. Можно понять ошибочно, - отсюда и разночтения, - но в споре это выяснится. По поводу "улучшить" - это вряд ли. Видимо, можно одни и те же правила читать в разных источниках: возможно другая формулировка и примеры "лягут" удачнее.

Comment: И еще: каждый руководствуется своими ориентирами в принятии решения. Например, обособление выражений, которые не являются вводными. Например, _фактически_ в начале предложения. Строгая грамматика предлагает не обособлять, т. к. это наречное выражение. Но в начале предложения это, да и многие другие словосочетания, могут приобретать значение вводности. Под влиянием местоположения они меняют свою функцию в целом. Получается, что влияет множество разных факторов: контекст, местоположение, возможность задать вопрос.

Comment: И нужно выбрать приоритет во всей этой иерархии. Но это все восходит к общей грамотности. Нужен человек, который, зная и учитывая все эти факторы, сможет дать правильное решение.

Comment: Я _"фактически"_ не обособляла, но в интернете читала дискуссии и видела, что многие люди задаются этим вопросом. Получается, что прочтение зависит от какой-то внутренней направленности тех или иных людей и во многом - от недостатка их образования.

Answer (score 2):

Когда кто-то обещает"быстро и без особых усилий " научить писать грамотно, так хочется сказать: "Вроде большенький, а в сказки веришь". Таков наш менталитет: лучше поверить в сказку, чем потрудиться. Видели мы  в своё время рекламу "Абсолютная грамотность за 11 занятий", только не пахло там грамотностью.Другое дело, если база уже хорошая, то блочное повторение+ практикум помогает, в прошлом году, например,у меня занимался взрослый человек, окончивший школу 8 лет назад,за 3 месяца до экзамена он вполне прилично подготовился и сдал на высокий балл, но это никак не "без особых усилий", усилия были колоссальные.

А всякие мифические курсы типа ЕШКО: включаешь диск и спишь, слушая и запоминая, - это мистификация, обман, проверяли.

А вот если без этих условий, то во времена моей юности в "Комсомолке"была статья.Девушка в вуз отлично сдала три предмета, а русский - на "два". Профессор взял её кандидатом на условии, что  она будет приносить ему за какой-то период( уже не помню: неделя-две) по общей тетради, где она будет переписывать "Войну и мир"Толстого. Она писала, сдавала, он бросал тетрадки, не читая. Плакала,но переписала весь роман. К концу первого курса это была самая грамотная студентка на курсе, перешла из кандидатов в нормальные студенты и училась на повышенную стипендию. Только вот это не быстрый и уж никак не лёгкий способ.Иногда я его советую самым уж неподдающимся. Не "Войну и мир", но Тургенева за лето переписывают, грамотность всё равно улучшается. Пишущий дважды читает, моторная память даёт о себе знать,рука сама запоминает, когда слова пишет , многократно их повторяя ,- принцип мерцающего повторения.

Comment: Есть два принципиально различных способа обучения грамотному письму: интуитивный и грамматический. Переписыванием мы развиваем интуицию (левое полушарие),  к примеру, маленькие цыганята прекрасно запоминают слова, где пишется О, а произносится А, причина же их не интересует, она им просто не нужна. Людям с развитой логикой (правое полушарие) грамматический метод намного ближе и понятнее. Кроме того, знание грамматики - это другой уровень освоения языка, это и есть настоящая грамотность.

Comment: Мое же личное убеждение состоит в том, что есть прекрасная и совершенная система русского письма и есть примитивные  методы ее описания, которые не позволяют людям в полной мере пользоваться нашей письменностью. И еще есть уверенность в том, что всё у нас прекрасно, методики - само совершенство,  а блочное повторение и многолетняя зубрежка правил - это именно то, что нужно. Без труда грамотным не станешь, только труд должен быть обязательно эффективным, но совсем не обязательно  длительным, тяжким, упорным и безрадостным.

Answer (score 1):

Плясать надо от печки, то есть ответить на вопрос: что значит "писать грамотно"? Если имеется в виду правописание в узком смысле, сиречь отображение слов на письме без орфографических ошибок, то необходимо твёрдо усвоить одну истину: русская орфография зиждется на морфологическом принципе. Приучив себя делить слова на значащие части (морфемы), даже если согласно синхроническому подходу сие невозможно, и зная большое количество этих самых морфем, что является, на мой взгляд, неизбежным следствием постоянного пользования языком, человек сможет легко писать без ошибок даже те слова, что до этого не употреблял.

Если речь идёт о грамотном словоизменении (и словообразовании) и согласовании слов, другими словами отсутствии ошибок грамматического и синтаксического характера, к которым относится пресловутая путаница в ться/тся, то следует усвоить вторую истину: русский язык преимущественно синтетический, после чего изучить природу и задачу спряжения/склонения слов.

Comment: Может быть, из того микса, который мы называем грамотным письмом, надо  выделить отдельные составляющие и изучать их отдельно: фонетику, словообразование, управление падежом, виды синтаксических конструкций и т.д., нельзя всё учить вперемешку. Сама наука письма - это только верхушка айсберга, и боюсь, что одним чтением хороших книг здесь не обойтись.

Comment: Разумеется, не обойтись. В отношении правописания книги могут помочь тем, у кого хорошая зрительная память, да и всё, пожалуй. Остальная их польза относится, скорее, к воспитанию собственной "литературности" и расширению словаря.

Answer (score 1):

Если быстро - то включить автокорректор и писать тексты на интересную тематику, обращая внимание на обнаруженные ошибки. С запятыми это не поможет, но за исключением совсем уж запущенных случаев, неточности в их употреблении мало кому заметны.

Comment: А что такое автокорректор?  Ваш метод я могла бы представить так: берешь интересную  тему, пишешь ее в свободном формате и в свободном полете своей фантазии  для себя, а потом несешь  к N на корректуру. Он исправляет ошибки и называет темы, теорию и практику которых надо проработать (это касается не только правописания, но и грамматики). Такой вариант выглядит неплохо.

Comment: @Vera так тоже можно. Более бюджетный вариант программа-корректор. Сейчас она встроена во все текстовые редакторы и почти во все интернет-браузеры. От большинства орфографических ошибок эта программа защитит

Comment: Программа-корректор с определенной точностью укажет на ошибки в конкретном тексте, но  вряд ли научит, и тем более быстро, грамотному письму. Ошибки нужно анализировать, определять их тематику, человек должен видеть всю картину, а не отдельные фрагменты, необходимо научиться  обобщать и накапливать знания.   Можно это делать самостоятельно, но тогда нужны хорошие способности и больше времени.

Comment: @Vera скажем я, подобным образом повысил свою грамотность со школьной двойки, до того, что орфографических ошибок почти не совершаю примерно за год общения на интересные мне темы. В среднем мы постоянно используем около 10 тыс. слов, что вполне реально просто запомнить.

Answer (score 1):

Уважаемая Вера, Вы же должны понимать, что **"быстро и без особых усилий"** достичь чего-то можно только при наличии особого дара, который мы называем талантом. А это такая вещь, как абсолютный слух. Он у человека или есть, или же его нет.

Что Вы подразумевали под "**писать грамотно**"? Грамотно составленную речь? Для этого должен быть развит интеллектуальный уровень. Если же речь идёт об орфографии, то тут опять должна быть развитая способность улавливать закономерности грамматики. А без этого есть только один способ - банальное и ленинское "Учиться, учиться и ещё раз учиться". Но это уже никак не получится "быстро и без особых усилий".

Comment: Вы совершенно справедливо отмечаете, что есть два показателя грамотности: написать на пять Тотальный диктант или уметь грамотно записывать собственную грамотную речь. Речь, скорее, идет о том, как "учиться, учиться и ещё раз учиться", по каким методикам: читать учебники с 1-11 класс, читать классику или выучить всего Розенталя. Может быть, есть наиболее эффективный метод именно для взрослых пользователей, которые относительно неплохо умеют говорить, но не умеют запятые ставить или ещё что-то не умеют.

Comment: Ааа, вот оно что?! Я не рискну ответить на этот вопрос. Точнее не рискну сделать выбор между учебниками 1-11 и Розенталем. (Читать классику исключаю, как неэффективный метод. Потому как читать и банально запоминать в каких случаях и как писалось у классиков вряд ли возможно. Да и вряд ли всё необходимое можно встретить в тех произведениях.)